# How to disable other button until a button is clicked

Tags: android, button, layout

I am new in android programming. I have made an app which is fill in the blanks type app. Until the answer-confirm button is clicked, the next and the previous Button should be disabled. If it is clicked and answer is checked, then next and previous Button to get enabled. please help!!!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please add some punctuation and upper case characters to your post?

Comment: Start with the Button in its disabled state. Then use `yourButton.setEnabled(true);` to enable the Button **after** the condition is met.

Comment: would you explain by dong it @bmarques

Comment: I put a code example as response @JunaidShaikh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a **button in xml** use this code

```
 <Button
android:text="Next"
android:id="@+id/my_button_del"
android:layout_width="72dp" 
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

for enabling the button when we click on previous then in **onClick function(previous)** add this code

```
next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

next is the button

Answer (score 0):

something like that (maybe its not the best way, you can play with it and make it better)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enableNextButton();
            }
        });
    ...
    }

    private void enableNextButton(){
        nextButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);
        nextButton.setClickable(true);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goNext();
            }
        });
    }

    private void disableNextButton(){
        nextButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
        nextButton.setClickable(false);
    }
```

and in your xml the buttons should be something like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/first_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/generic_button_heigth"
    android:background="@drawable/button_active"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/generic_margin"
    android:text="@string/first_button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/generic_button_heigth"
    android:background="@drawable/button_inactive"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/generic_margin"
    android:text="@string/next_button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

this way you start with an active button and an inactive button, when the first is pressed you can "activate" the next button

Comment: its not working @bmarques, i want it to get disabled until the conform button is pressed when the user is done typing the answer, and when the conform button  is pressed it should work again as normal and show the next question, and then it should be disabled ,please help!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Please use punctuations and uppercases but anyway.

You can check here for more infos about buttons : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Otherwise, the method `setVisible()` allow you to make visibile or not a button of your layout. Set button visibility to `GONE` (button will be completely "removed" -- the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or `INVISIBLE` (button will became "transparent" -- its space will not be available for another widgets):

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or in xml:

```
<Button ... android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**EDIT**

Oh sorry ! So you can use `setEnabled()`.

Comment: i just want to make it disabled @Maxouille

Comment: mCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer();
                if (mCheckAnswer.isEnabled()){
                    mNext.setEnabled(true);
                    mPrev.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    mNext.setEnabled(false);
                    mPrev.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Edit your first post to have the coloration plz

Comment: please help i could not get it please help